# Android: in RecyclerView Adapter how do I test if an entry from SQLite database isNull?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  The CardViews show user entered data that is stored in a SQLite database.  One of the data fields from the database is a DueDate thtat stores a date from a DatePicker.  If the user does not enter a DueDate then the SQLite database entry for the DueDate column is "NULL".

I would like to test in onBindViewHolder() whether the DueDate entry is "NULL" or not.  What am I missing here?

Model file is Contact.java:

```
private String duedate;
...
public String getDuedate() {
    return duedate;
}
```

RecyclerView Adapter.java:

```
...
private List<Contact> contactList;
public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
}
...
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    final Contact contact = contactList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    final ContactHolder holder = (ContactHolder) viewHolder; 

    *** here is where I'm lost ***
    if (contact.getDuedate() = isNull) { // If no DueDate, setText below.
        holder.cardBlankText10.setText("DueDate not entered");
    } else {    
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*** here is where I'm lost ***
    if (contact.getDuedate() == null) { // If no DueDate, setText below.
        holder.cardBlankText10.setText("DueDate not entered");
    } else {
```

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  I used "=" instead of "==".

Comment: comparision with `= null` will return boolean. You mean you try correctly?

Comment: App doesn't crash but it doesn't setText so not sure what is happening.

Comment: Give some examples?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14931079)

Comment: @Micho why do you think this is `not provide an answer to the question`?
I saw him use wrong `isNull` then i correct it without see any other wrong code?

Comment: @TruongHieu add an explanation to your answer instead of providing code only answers.

Comment: @TruongHieu  the setText issue is separate so I will ask another question for that issue.  I have accepted and upvoted your answer on this question, cheers.

Comment: @TruongHieu  Is "if(contact.getDuedate) = null)" also correct with only one equals sign?  Or do I definitely need to use "=="?

Comment: @Micho thanks. I'll take a look.
@AJW `only one equals sign` is for set, eg. a = 1, b = 2.
But `two equals sign` is comparision, meaning if a = b or not.
So if you want to compare, you **have to** use `two equals sign`